# Is it possible to convert system of linear equations to transportation problem?

Tags: optimization

I was just wondering this while studying optimization methods. But I dont know how to define a transportation network. I want to do this for arbitrary matrix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Transportation problems rely on a network (oriented graph) structure whose constraint matrices are 0-1. Usually linear constraint systems are not equivalent to this smaller class of constraints.